# Can a bootstrap carousel rotate carousel-items of two different carousel IDs?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a simple BS 4 carousel that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <a class="carousel-control-prev text-dark" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-dark" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="container carousel slide w-100 pointer-event" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Next and Previous clicks are rotating the carousel items of #myCarousel.

Now, is it possible to also rotate carousel items of another div with a different ID along with the rotation of #myCarousel items?

This is my second content that I want to rotate along with the first set of items using the same Next/Previous clicks:

```
<div id="second-carousel" class="col-sm-7 carousel slide w-100 pointer-event">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div id="first" class="carousel-item active"></div>
        <div id="second" class="carousel-item"></div>
        <div id="third" class="carousel-item"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the events from first carousel to programmatically change the second.

The event object contains the state and includes properties `to` and `from`

```
$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e){   
    $("#myCarousel2").carousel(e.to);    
});
```

[Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPHSBPX7TQ30)